# Identifying "bad" data combinations in Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have a spreadsheet of employee data (time charged to projects and customers) that is tens of thousands of rows long.  Each month, the file is updated to include the most recent month data. Each row represents one employee's charges (each employee generally has multiple charges each month).

I need to identify approximately 10-15 "bad combinations" of data, where essentially employees are charging time to the wrong customer/project, etc.  For example, the "QC-Europe" team should not be charging to customer "Ford" and the "Engineering" department should not be using the sub-process of "Design", etc etc.

I'm debating the best approach for this.  My current path is to create tables of all "good combinations" and do lookups off of that, but maybe there is a more efficient method?  Thanks!

rough file layout:

```
Employee   Dept          Sub-Process   Customer  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  etc
Joe        Engineering   Build         Ford       10   15   8    30
```

Comment: probably not ... the spreadsheet has no way to identify bad data without some type of a list ... an improvement would be to use a database program

Comment: As @jsotola suggest,s, conditions for questionable and invalid entries could be kept in a small table, and queries performed using that table. MS Office might include *Access*, but there are numerous excellent free databases, such as LibreOffice *Base*, MySQL, Firebird, etc. See https://www.fivetran.com/learn/open-source-database

Comment: If I were doing this in excel I would probaby specifically look for the 10-15 bad combinations rather than identifying the unknown number of good combinations (unless that number was less than 15).

Comment: Off topic, but in parallel I would be asking why the (assumed) project management system is allowing these bad combinations to be entered in the first place.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  The longer term solution is to limit the initial data entry to avoid these "bad combinations" (thanks gns100).  For now I have to deal with the hand I have been dealt with.  As someone mentioned above, I am creating tables of "good combinations" that I am using XLOOKUP against.  But as you can imagine, just creating the tables is time consuming, but I think once those are done, the actual formula creation should be quick.  The database solution is likely better than Excel, but the team wants to keep this all within Excel for easier maintenance. Thanks all!!